# GitHub Create gist api call showing invalid email address

Tags: php, html, github

I am working on github gist API to create new gists using php, gists are creating but not showing in the list.

getting "invalid-email-address" as output.

below is the code

```
$headers = array(
        'User-Agent: PHP',
        'X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user, gist',
        'X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user, gist'
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    # Sending the data using cURL
    $url = 'https://api.github.com/gists';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($your_resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

[image: getting below output]